# Can mdcss style guide work with browsersync?

Tags: html, css, markdown, reload, browser-sync

Has anyone had success getting the [mdcss](https://github.com/jonathantneal/mdcss) style guide to work with [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/)?

The issue seems to be the body tag in the index.html that mdcss generates. If I write one in manually, the page reloads when it's supposed to, but otherwise I don't get any page reloading.

mdcss recreates index.html every time it's run, so manually adding a body tag isn't a long term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actively using both together and it works flawlessly. I'm running it on browsersync's server port, it just injects the scripts needed on load and with the right reload commands it just refreshes as needed.

Here's the relevant bits from my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['css'], () => {
  'use strict';
  browserSync.init({
    port:        8080,
    server:      './styleguide',
    notify:      false
  });

  gulp.watch('src/**/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.md', ['css']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('css', () => {
  'use strict';
  const options = {
    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
  };
  const processors = [
    stylelint,
    postcssImport({ glob: true }),
    apply,
    simpleVars,
    customMedia,
    customSelectors,
    cssVariables,
    nested,
    autoprefixer({ browsers: options.browsers }),
    mdcss({
      theme: mdcssGithub({
        title:    'Styleguide',
        examples: {
          css:     ['style.css'],
          bodyjs:  ['js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js']
        }
      }),
      assets: ['js']
    })
  ];
  return gulp.src('./src/*.css')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('styleguide'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Then goto http://localhost:8080